# C++ Binary File I/O Operations Slow Down... How DB Handle Binary Files?

Tags: c++, fstream, binaryfiles, c++-ios

I am trying to make a simple file-based hash table. Here is my `insert` member function:

```
private: std::fstream f;  // std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary

public: void insert(const char* this_key, long this_value) {
    char* that_key;
    long that_value;
    long this_hash = std::hash<std::string>{}(this_key) % M;
    long that_hash;  // also block status

    long block = this_hash;
    long offset = block * BLOCK_SIZE;
    while (true) {
        this->f.seekg(offset);
        this->f.read((char*) &that_hash, sizeof(long));
        if (that_hash > -1) {  // -1 (by default) indicates a never allocated block
            this->f.read(that_key, BLOCK_SIZE);
            if (strcmp(this_key, that_key) == 0) {
                this->f.seekp(this->f.tellg());
                this->f.write((char*) &this_value, sizeof(long));
                break;
            } else {
                block = (block + 1) % M;  // linear probing
                offset = block * BLOCK_SIZE;
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            this->f.seekp(offset);
            this->f.write((char*) &this_hash, sizeof(long));  // as block status
            this->f.write(this_key, KEY_SIZE);
            this->f.write((char*) &this_value, sizeof(long));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Tests up to 10M key, value pairs with 50,000,017 blocks were fairly done. (Binary file size was about 3.8GB).

However, a test with 50M keys and 250,000,013 blocks extremely slows down... (Binary file size was more than 19GB in this case). 1,000 `insert`s usually takes 4~5ms but exceptionally take more than 2,000ms. It gets slower and slower then takes 40~150ms... (x10 ~ x30 slower...) I definitely have no idea...

- What causes this exceptional binary file I/O slowing down?
- Do `seekg`&`seekp` and other I/O operations are affected by file size? (I could not find any references about this question though...)
- How key, value stores and databases avoid this I/O slow down?
- How can I solve this problem?

Comment: One reason that can cause slowdown with large data is that any cache eventually get full so at some point you might have to *always* reload data from a slow medium. How to prevent slowdown? (1) Add more memory and (2) Ensure that data is structured in a way to minimize invalidation of the cache (locality of data that is expected to be accessed at one point in time). Thus the physical structure of the data should be compatible with the access pattern. In your case, if linear probing occurs very often with bigger data, then you will get a slowdown.

Comment: @Phil1970 What do you mean by 'add more memory'? If it is about RAM, it uses almost 0 memory... Or, can I increase cache somewhere in RAM? Can you give me any reference to start with?

Comment: @Phil1970 From `free -m -h`, I can find `cached` column. You may said this? How can I increase it?

Comment: The fact that your application don't use much memory does mean that the OS does not use memory for file caching. The first thing you should do it to check memory and disk usage using tools. Then the next thing to do would be to use a profiler or do some statistics to see how your program behave.

Comment: @Phil1970 I did not do anything to utilize memory... How can I do? Any references for practice please? In addition, then file side should be less than `cached` memory?

Comment: What are the values of `BLOCK_SIZE`, `KEY_SIZE` and `M` in your case? How much RAM your computer have and how much is used when running that code? What is the disk usage? Do you have fast SSD drives? What is the percentage of linear probing done (when using hashing, you have to minimize collisions).

Comment: @Phil1970 Following your advice, I am trying to reduce file size. BLOCK_SIZE (80->40), KEY_SIZE (64->24), and M (250,000,013 -> 100,000,007 to store 50M pairs, collision rate increases from 20~30% to 50~60% but seems faster!) to reduce file size. Is how much portion of RAM is used for caching solely determined by OS? Or, can I increase it?

Comment: You could listen that video to get an idea of what can affect performance on modern CPU: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICKIMHCw--Y (CPU design effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data size**

Usually disk drive block size are a power of 2 so if your data block size is also a power of 2, then you can essentially eliminate the case where a data block cross a disk block boundary.

In your case, a value of 64 bytes (or 32 bytes if you don't really need to store the hash) might somewhat perform a bit better.

**Insertion order**

The other thing you could do to improve performance is to do your insertion is increasing hash order to reduce the number of a time data must be loaded from the disk.

Generally when data is read or written to the disk, the OS will read/write a large chuck at a time (maybe 4k) so if your algorithm is written is a way to write data locally in time, you will reduce the number of time data must actually be read or written to the disk.

Given that you make a lot of insertion, one possibility would be to process insertion in batch of say 1000 or even 10000 key/value pair at a time. Essentially, you would accumulate data in memory and sort it and once you have enough item (or when you are done inserting), you will then write the data in order.

That way, you should be able to reduce disk access which is very slow. This is probably even more important if you are using traditional hard drive as moving the head is slow (in which case, it might be useful to defragment it). Also, be sure that your hard drive have more than enough free space.

In some case, local caching (in your application) might also be helpful particularly if you are aware how your data is used.

**File size VS collisions**

When you use an hash, you want to find the sweet spot between file size and collisions. If you have too much collisions, then you will waste lot of time and at some point it might degenerate when it become hard to find a free place for almost every insertion.

On the other hand, if your file is really very large, you might end up in a case where you might fill your RAM with data that is mainly empty and still need to replace data with data from the disk on almost all insertion.

For example, if your data is 20GB and you are able to load say 2 GB in memory, then if insert are really random, 90% of the time you might need real access to hard drive.

**Configuration**

Well options will depends on the OS and it is beyond the scope of a programming forum. If you want to optimize your computer, then you should look elsewhere.

**Reading**

It might be helpful to read about operating systems (file system, cache layer…) and algorithms (external sorting algorithms, B-Tree and other structures) to get a better understanding.

**Alternatives**

- Extra RAM
- Fast SSD
- Multithreading (for ex. input and output threads)
- Rewriting of the algorithm (for ex. to read/write a whole disk page at once)
- Faster CPU / 64 bit computer
- Using algorithms designed for such scenarios.
- Using a database.
- Profiling code
- Tuning parameters

Comment: Thank you, I learned seriously a lot! The default chunk size for a memory cache is a multiple of KB. It is huge... So, it seems like if I reduce the memory cache size (probably impossible?) or replace key of `BLOCK_SIZE` `char`s with 1 `long` pointing to somewhere in a file sequentially storing key list without empty space, I may get cache more 'valuable' chunks of files into memory and achieve performance gain. Is it right?

Comment: At some point, you have to do your own tests with your data and decide how much effort you want to invest in that.

Comment: Sure, sure. Just for asking advice about approaches. :D